# Using Nomad optimization solver in R with categorical variables

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, solver

I use `snomadr` (http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/crs/versions/0.15-24/topics/snomadr), the R interface to the Nomad optimization solver.

It works very well, however in the package description, there is no example where this solver is used with categorical variables (using bbin = 2).

When trying to do so in `snomadr`, I get an error message :

> NOMAD has been interrupted ( NOMAD::Exception thrown (Mads.cpp, 574)
>   NOMAD::Exception thrown (Mads.cpp, 318) categorical variables:
>   parameter NEIGHBORS_EXE is undefined )

which indicates that the entry format for categorical variables is wrong. Does anyone have a code example using categorical variables in `srnomad` ?

Comment: You need to show minimal data and code to reproduce the error.  Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Without beeing an R user: the docs of nomad say ```solving problems with categorical variables requires to define the neighbours
of the current iterate.```. See [here](https://www.gerad.ca/nomad/Downloads/user_guide.pdf) (chapter 7.1). This should also apply to your wrapper, the only question beeing if you have to provide these neighborhoods by callback (like done when using the solver directly;there are examples mentioned) or if the wrapper can do that automatically (what i would not assume).Sadly, i didn't find anything about defining this neighborhood in snomadr's docs. Maye ask the author